# Line chart colors by category in python

Tags: python, pandas, charts, line

I would like to create a line plot with the number of sales by month with the following dataframe called consola:

```
Date Console    Sales   Units sold 
01/01/2020  Switch  480000  2000
01/01/2020  Xbox    288000  1200 
01/01/2020  PS5 552000  2300
01/02/2020  Switch  349440  1456 
01/02/2020  Xbox    236880  987
01/02/2020  PS5 429360  1789 
01/03/2020  Switch  523200  2180
01/03/2020  Xbox    480000  2000 
01/03/2020  PS5 662400  2760
01/04/2020  Switch  426480  1777 
01/04/2020  Xbox    296400  1235
01/04/2020  PS5 444960  1854 
01/05/2020  Switch  600000  2500
01/05/2020  Xbox    396000  1650 
01/05/2020  PS5 456000  1900
```

So I've created something simple:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

consola = pd.read_csv('c:/consola.csv') 

ax.plot(consola.index, consola['Sales'])

ax.set_xlabel('Date')

ax.set_ylabel("Sales")

ax.legend(['Console'], loc="upper left")

plt.show()
```

And worked. But I  would like to have a line per category within the Console column (for example a red line for Switch an green for Xbox). But can't make it...
I believe it should be something simple but I am pretty new in python and I am stuck...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot( x=df["Date"],y=df["Sales"],hue=df["Console"])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That was going to be my option #2. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
consola.set_index(['Date','Console'])['Sales'].unstack().plot()
```

Output:

[image]